# enumerating all the maximal independent sets of a graph using backtracking

Tags: java, python-2.7

I'm looking for an algorithm that generates maximal independent sets for a given graph, in java or python using backtracking, the running time is not that important as long as it does the job. Thanks.

Comment: This was a very thin problem description. Could you update with an example, initial data and wanted result?

Comment: given a graph G I want to generate all the possible Independent set instances such that they are maximal at each time, using some recursive backtracking method. at each time a node is either put in the set and all it's neighbors get deleted else the node is not put in the set and it itself gets deleted

Comment: This expanded the problem description a bit (you could very well update the question directly instead of adding as a comment), but I still think an example is essential. Create a drawing with some nodes and assign values. Then describe exactly what results you are looking for for that particular example.